# Error while using SSMS 2016 : Object cannot be cast from DBNull to other types

Tags: sql, sql-server, ssms, windows-10, sql-server-2016

Can anyone resolve this issue:

**SQL Server Management Studio 2016 CTP3 (13.0.900.73) on a Windows 10 Laptop**

1. Object Explorer > Server > Databases > Database
2. Right Click - Properties

Instead of getting the Database Properties dialogue box I instead get this pop-up:

### TITLE: Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio

Cannot show requested dialog.

---

ADDITIONAL INFORMATION:

Cannot show requested dialog. (SqlMgmt)

---

Object cannot be cast from DBNull to other types. (mscorlib)

---

BUTTONS:

### OK

Edit:

Issue is occuring on-Prem with both physical and virtual machines. It is also happening on Amazon RDS servers.

If I use another laptop with Win 7 and SSMS 2014 I don't get any issues.

If I remove SSMS 2016 and install SSMS 2014 I get graphics issues as SSMS 2014 dialogue boxes get distorted as I have a high definition computer and SSMS 2014 throws a shoe.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This appears to be the same issue that is logged in [this Microsoft Connect item](https://connect.microsoft.com/SQLServer/feedback/details/2135289/error-object-cannot-be-cast-from-dbnull-to-other-types-mscorlib). The fix for this issue should be available in the SSMS January preview release.

Answer (score 1):

I've seen this happen if the database is in 'Recovery' mode or the DB's files are not accessible because of permissions or something like a disconnected drive.

Agreed that the dialog they show really isn't helpful.

Comment: I'm getting this error on Phyical and Virtual boxes in my domain and on servers up at Amazon RDS.

If I use another laptop with Win 7 / SSMS 2014 I have no issues.