# Management Studio 2014 doesn't like my Surface Book

Tags: sql, sql-server, ssms, windows-10

It'll install and run but dialogue boxes get all crazy and distorted as to be unusable.

I'm told it's due to my high definition screen.

Any ideas how to fix this?

[image: New Server Registration]

Comment: Does this help: http://spaghettidba.com/2015/10/14/ssms-in-high-dpi-displays-how-to-stop-the-madness/ ??

Comment: I tried this solution and it's now big n chunky on my external display and "okay" on my laptop display.

Unfortunately the dialogue box for registering a CMS still looks like garbage.  (See image attached to the original message)

Comment: If it's an option to use this instead, I saw there's a release (pre-release?) of SSMS 2016 that specifically mentioned support for hdpi screens.

Comment: Peter - I'm using SSMS 2016 and it's great  apart from the fact I get a seemingly meaningless error message when I try to get database properties from object explorer.

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34750903/error-while-using-ssms-2016-object-cannot-be-cast-from-dbnull-to-other-types/34751351#34751351